# Average height of males and females for each of the 50 US states: Where can I download the data?

Tags: data-request, usa

Where can I download data for average height of males and females for each of the individual 50 states?

RAW data or SQL data is fine, it does not have to be charted or formatted - I can do that myself - just can't find any data.

Answer (score 5):

The BRFSS would be a good data set to use for this question. Download the data [here](http://www.cdc.gov/brfss/annual_data/annual_data.htm).

For example, for the [2013 data](http://www.cdc.gov/brfss/annual_data/annual_2013.html), I recommend getting acquainted with the [codebook](http://www.cdc.gov/brfss/annual_data/2013/pdf/CODEBOOK13_LLCP.pdf) and then downloading the [raw data](http://www.cdc.gov/brfss/annual_data/2013/files/LLCP2013ASC.ZIP). It will be an ASCII fixed column width raw file, so refer to the [column positions](http://www.cdc.gov/brfss/annual_data/2013/LLCP_VarLayout_13_OneColumn.HTML) document for transferring to the analysis package of your choice.

Comment: I had previous uploaded BRFSS 2006 data to Socrata (an open data analysis, visualization, and export platform) and have created a filtered view for you at https://communities.socrata.com/Health/CDC-BRFSS-Annual-Data-2006-Selection-of-Columns-he/5vep-jk5c which you can download the raw data from.

Comment: Note that per the codebook, the majority of respondents (349,187) responded to `HEIGHT3` column with a value between 200 and 711 which means `Height (ft/inches)  Notes: 0 _ / _ _ = feet / inches` -- I think that means a value of 412 is 4'12" and so you will need to download and run your own analysis. Disclosure: I work for Socrata.

Comment: @Skram - I see you took a new job at Socrata!